# How to Fetch record from another table which is having multiple record for same id?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have table structures as follows

```
table-1
-------
id
name


table-2
--------
imageId
id ( reference of table1.id)
image
```

and table1 has the following record

```
id     name 
1      A
2      B
3      C
```

Table 2 has

```
imageId      id          image
1             1         image1.jpg
2             1         image2.jpg
3             2         image3.jpg
```

i.e, table1.id has many images in table2, now i need to select the record and its corresponding images(multiple images for same id), like

```
id   name       image
1     A         image1.jpg,image2.jpg
2     B         image3.jpg
```

Comment: you should check Joins in SQL. it's all you need.

Comment: @hardik thanks for your suggestion, i tried joins but **Zane Bien** given the exact answer what i needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `GROUP_CONCAT` function to get values across multiple rows into a single comma-delimited string (such as how you have in your example desired result):

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, GROUP_CONCAT(b.image) AS images
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    b.imageId,
    a.id,
    b.imageName
from
    table-1 a
    right outer join table-2
        on a.id=b.id
```

This will give you an output of:

```
id   name       image

1     A         image1.jpg
1     A         image2.jpg
2     B         image3.jpg
```